Programmatically setting property
In my micronaut microservice, I am trying to set a property programmatically instead of adding it inside application.yml. I have provided my code below, also error that I am getting. How can fix this, or is there a different way to achieve this?
Code:
import io.micronaut.context.env.ActiveEnvironment;
import io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySource;
import io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourceLoader;
import io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventListener;
import io.micronaut.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@Singleton
public class CustomConfigSource implements PropertySourceLoader {

    @Override
    public Optional<PropertySource> load(String resourceName, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("this.is.property.name", "value");
        return Optional.of(PropertySource.of("custom", properties));
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<PropertySource> loadEnv(String resourceName, ResourceLoader resourceLoader, ActiveEnvironment activeEnvironment) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> read(String name, InputStream input) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}

Access:
@Property(name = "this.is.property.name")
private String myProperty;

Error:
io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor: Unexpected error occurred: Failed to inject value for field [myProperty]

I have tried to add logs, and I see methods inside CustomConfigSource such as load, loadEnv are not being called.

There is a way to achive this
public class CustomContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment();

        Map<String, Object> myProperties = new HashMap<>();
        myProperties.put("this.is.property.name", "value");
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
                new MapPropertySource("custom", myProperties));
    }
}

register this on startup
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(StarterMain.class)
            .initializers(new CustomContextInitializer())
            .run(args);

Use your property
@Value("${this.is.property.name}")
private String myProperty;

