unable to feed property programmatically
In my micronaut microservice, I am trying to feed a property my.property.name programatically instead of adding it to the application.yml. I have provided my code below and error I am getting. What should I do to fix this?
Code Approach-1:
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Context;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires;
import io.micronaut.context.env.ActiveEnvironment;
import io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySource;
import io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySourceLoader;
import io.micronaut.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import io.micronaut.core.util.CollectionUtils;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@Singleton
@Requires(beans = MyService.class)
@Context
public class MyPropertySourceLoader implements PropertySourceLoader {

    private final MyService myService;

    @Inject
    public MyPropertySourceLoader(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<PropertySource> load(String resourceName, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {

        String myPropertyValue = myService.getProperty("id");
        return Optional.of(PropertySource.of("custom-property", Collections.singletonMap("my.property.name", myPropertyValue), -10000));
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<PropertySource> loadEnv(String resourceName, ResourceLoader resourceLoader, ActiveEnvironment activeEnvironment) {

        String myPropertyValue = myService.getProperty("id");
        return Optional.of(PropertySource.of("custom-property", Collections.singletonMap("my.property.name", myPropertyValue), -10000));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> read(String name, InputStream input) throws IOException {

        String myPropertyValue =myService.getProperty("id");
        return CollectionUtils.mapOf("my.property.name", myPropertyValue);
    }
}

Code Approach-2:

 import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Context;
 import io.micronaut.context.env.Environment;
 import io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySource;
 import io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventListener;
 import io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent;
 import jakarta.inject.Inject;
 import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;

 @Singleton
 @Context
 @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) // Ensure this listener is invoked early
 public class PropertyAddingListener implements ApplicationEventListener<StartupEvent> {

    @Inject private Environment environment;

    private final MyService myService;

    @Inject
    public PropertyAddingListener(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(StartupEvent event) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("my.property.name", myService.getProperty("id"));

        PropertySource propertySource = PropertySource.of("customSource", properties, -10000);
        environment.addPropertySource(propertySource);
    }
 }

Error same in both approaches:
ERROR 2024-05-10 21:27:34,040  [main] io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut: Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.config.DefaultKafkaConsumerConfiguration]

Message: Could not resolve placeholder ${my.property.name}
Path Taken: new KafkaConsumerProcessor(........

I have tried different approaches and but I am getting same error. I have tried increasing precedence of feeding the my.property.name by using @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) etc. but I am facing same error. What how to fix this issue, or is there any alternative approach to achieve this?

I believe this question is a duplicate from same OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78475403/programmatically-setting-property
